# Django Form Says "field is required" Even When it Exists in POST Body

Tags: python, django, forms, models

Django form isn't accepting POST (is_valid is False) even when all required fields are present in POST.

I'm using a simple Form but dynamically generating form fields using the results of a query from a different model. Using the guidance from: https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

**My View:**

```
def questionnaire(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        questionnaire_form = Questionnaire(request.POST)
        if questionnaire_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            return render(request, 'questionnaire.html', {'form': Questionnaire()})
    else:

        return render(request, 'questionnaire.html', {'form': Questionnaire()})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

**My Form**

```
class Questionnaire(forms.Form):
vendor = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10, label="Vendor ID")

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    fieldlist = OrderedDict()
    for item in ControlQuestions.objects.all():
        fieldlist[str(item.control_id)] = item.question
    super(Questionnaire, self).__init__(fieldlist, *args, **kwargs)
    for item in fieldlist:
        self.fields[item] = forms.BooleanField(label=fieldlist[item], initial="False")
```

**request.body**

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=****&vendor=1&1=on&2=on&3=on
```

**questionnaire_form.errors**

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>vendor<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```